# Find the generic type

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

Throughout reflection is there a way of achieving this?
get `IDictionary<,>` from `IDictionary<int,int>`, per instance?

my intention is:

```
 typeof(UniqueKeyQuery<,>).IsAssignableFrom(query.GetType())
```

Whereas '**query**' is of type `UniqueKeyQuery<Sometype,int>`.
I don`t want to compare names, as I want to UniqueKeyQuery to be extensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
typeof(UniqueKeyQuery<,>).IsAssignableFrom(query.GetType().GetGenericDefitition())
```

If it doesn't work, you can use this (a static extension method that should be in a static class)

```
public static bool IsOrInheritsGenericDefinition(this Type ThisType, Type GenericDefinition, out Type DefinitionWithTypedParameters)
    {
        DefinitionWithTypedParameters = ThisType;

        while (DefinitionWithTypedParameters != null)
        {
            if (DefinitionWithTypedParameters.IsGenericType)
            {
                if (DefinitionWithTypedParameters.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == GenericDefinition)
                    return true;
            }

            DefinitionWithTypedParameters = DefinitionWithTypedParameters.BaseType;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Call that by:

```
Type QueryType;
query.GetType().IsOrInheritsGenericDefinition(typeof(UniqueKeyQuery<,>), out QueryType);
```

Comment: I believe `IsAssignableFrom` wouldn't work, because you can never assign a generic type with no type parameters. Maybe that's the reason I made that method in my codes.

Comment: Your implementation worked like a charm. Thank you, I did put much thinking in case of validation when it inherits from UniqueKeyQuery, and this new class is not generic.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the "open" generic type of (eg., `query`) [GetGenericTypeDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) would work:

```
 typeof(UniqueKeyQuery<,>).IsAssignableFrom(
     query.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()
 )
```